# How to update metric values in prometheus exporter (golang)

Tags: go, prometheus, exporter

I'm starting to write an own prometheus exporter using golang.
I think I got the basics but I don't know what to do exactly to get the value of the metric up to date. Using Set only does it once.
It is not changing on runtime.

What I have so far:

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
  "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"

  "time"
  "io/ioutil"
  "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
  "strconv"
)

var (
  sidekiqProcessed = setGaugeMetric("sidekiq_processed", "Sidekiq Processed", "lable", "lablevalue")
)

func setGaugeMetric(name string, help string, label string, labelvalue string) (prometheusGauge prometheus.Gauge) {
  var (
    gaugeMetric = prometheus.NewGauge(prometheus.GaugeOpts{
      Name: name,
      Help: help,
      ConstLabels: prometheus.Labels{label: labelvalue},
    })
  )

  return gaugeMetric
}

func getSidekiqProcessed() (sidekiq float64) {
  body := getContent("http://example.com/sidekiq/stats")
  processed := gjson.Get(body, "sidekiq.processed")
  conv, err := strconv.ParseFloat(processed.String(), 64)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  return conv
}

func getContent(url string) (body string) {
  httpClient := &http.Client{Timeout: 10 * time.Second}
  res, err := httpClient.Get(url)

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
  res.Body.Close()

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  return string(content)
}

func init() {
  prometheus.MustRegister(sidekiqProcessed)
}

func main() {
  sidekiqProcessed.Set(getSidekiqProcessed())

  // The Handler function provides a default handler to expose metrics
  // via an HTTP server. "/metrics" is the usual endpoint for that.
  http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Read something about Collector but have no clue how to implement it.
Can somebody help me to complete/correct my code so that the value of the metric also updates at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of custom collector (from https://www.robustperception.io/setting-a-prometheus-counter):

```
package main

import "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"

type MyCollector struct {
  counterDesc *prometheus.Desc
}

func (c *MyCollector) Describe(ch chan<- *prometheus.Desc) {
  ch <- c.counterDesc
}

func (c *MyCollector) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {
  value := 1.0 // Your code to fetch the counter value goes here.
  ch <- prometheus.MustNewConstMetric(
    c.counterDesc,
    prometheus.CounterValue,
    value,
  )
}

func NewMyCollector() *MyCollector {
  return &MyCollector{
    counterDesc: prometheus.NewDesc("my_counter_total", "Help string", nil, nil),
  }
}

// To hook in the collector: prometheus.MustRegister(NewMyCollector())
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to implement a collector instead, and run the http request when the Prometheus server scrapes. [See the best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#collectors).

> When implementing the collector for your exporter, you should never use the usual direct instrumentation approach and then update the metrics on each scrape.
>
> Rather create new metrics each time. In Go this is done with MustNewConstMetric in your Update() method. For Python see https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#custom-collectors and for Java generate a List in your collect method, see StandardExports.java for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The [github.com/prometheus/client_golang](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang) library may be non-trivial to use when writing Prometheus exporters in Go. Try https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics library instead. It is much easier to use in general. See the following code as an example, which allows dynamically updating `sidekiq_processed` metric with the given label:

```golang
import (
  "fmt"

  "github.com/VictoriaMetrics/metrics"
)

// UpdateSidekiqProcessed updates `sidekiq_processed{label="<labelValue>"}` metric to the given value
func UpdateSidekiqProcessed(labelValue string, value float64) {
  metricName := fmt.Sprintf("sidekiq_processed{label=%q}", labelValue)
  metrics.GetOrCreateFloatCounter(metricName).Set(value)
}
```